# Expected "," but " " found

Tags: react-native, splash-screen, react-native-ios

I get some error when i want to link react-native-splash-screen

````
SyntaxError: Expected "," but " " found.
    at peg$buildStructuredError (D:\Havah\havah\node_modules\xcode\lib\parser\pbxproj.js:429:12)
    at Object.peg$parse [as parse] (D:\Havah\havah\node_modules\xcode\lib\parser\pbxproj.js:1891:11)
    at pbxProject.parseSync (D:\Havah\havah\node_modules\xcode\lib\pbxProject.js:63:24)
    at isInstalled (D:\Havah\havah\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-ios\build\link\isInstalled.js:44:67)
    at Object.isInstalled (D:\Havah\havah\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-ios\build\link\common\isInstalled.js:23:35)
    at Object.keys.forEach.platform (D:\Havah\havah\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\link\linkDependency.js:53:36)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at linkDependency (D:\Havah\havah\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\link\linkDependency.js:36:32)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)```
````